# Natural Deduction Problem: Predicate Logic with Identity in a Gentzen-style system

Tags: natural-deduction

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:

> $$\left\{\forall x (Qx \leftrightarrow (\exists y (Rxy \wedge \neg x = y))),\quad \forall x Qx,\quad \exists x \exists y \forall z (z = x \vee z = y)\right\} \models \forall x \forall y (Rxy \leftrightarrow Ryx)$$

I can see that the brunt of the proof will come from making a contradiction between the identities in the conjunction and those in the first premise, but I'm not sure. Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old now, but I can confirm that there exists a direct proof for this that is very long and ugly - the third premise means that everything in the domain is split into two sets, those that are equal to $a$ and those that are equal to $b$. Once you instantiate for your universals in the conclusion, and your existentials in the first premise, you can check for each disjunct for each of your variables. A whole bunch will result in contradictions, because of what you get from instantiating premise 1. Those that don't, will be cases where the things in the conclusion are the same, so ($Raa$ iff $Raa$), or you'll have gotten the case where $a\neq b$, but will have that $Rab$ and $Rba$, so $Rab$ iff $Rba$.

Answer (score 0):

```
01. ∀x[Qx↔[∃y[[Rxy]∧¬[x=y]]]] premise
02. ∀xQx                      premise
03. ∃x∃y∀z[[z=x]∨[z=y]]       premise
   04. ∃y∀z[[z=a]∨[z=y]]        assumption
      05. ∀z[[z=a]∨[z=b]]         assumption
         06. Rcd                    assumption
            07. ¬[c=d]                assumption
            08. ∀x[Qx↔[∃y[[Rxy]∧¬[x=y]]]] restate 01
            09. Qd↔[∃y[[Rdy]∧¬[d=y]]] ∀elim 08
            10. ∀xQx                  restate 02
            11. Qd                    ∀elim 10
            12. ∃y[[Rdy]∧¬[d=y]]      ↔elim 09 11
               13. [Rde]∧¬[d=e]         assumption
                  14. e=c                 assumption
                  15. [Rde]∧¬[d=e]        restate 13
                  16. [Rdc]∧¬[d=c]        para 15 14
                  17. Rdc                 ∧elim 16
               18. [e=c]→[Rdc]          →intro 19 17
                  19. ¬[e=c]              assumption
                  20. ∀z[[z=a]∨[z=b]]     restate 05
                  21. [c=a]∨[c=b]         ∀elim 20
                  22. [d=a]∨[d=b]         ∀elim 20
                  23. [e=a]∨[e=b]         ∀elim 20
                  24. [Rde]∧¬[d=e]        restate 13
                  25. ¬[d=e]              ∧elim 24
                     26. e=a                assumption
                     27. ¬[d=e]             restate 25
                     28. ¬[d=a]             para 27 26
                     29. [d=a]∨[d=b]        restate 22
                     30. d=b                ∨elim 29 28
                     31. ¬[e=c]             restate 19
                     32. ¬[a=c]             para 31 26
                     33. ¬[c=a]             flip 32
                     34. [c=a]∨[c=b]        restate 21
                     35. c=b                ∨elim 34 33
                     36. ¬[c=d]             restate 07
                     37. c=d                para 35 30
                     38. ⊥                  36 37
                  39. ¬[e=a]              ¬intro 26 38
                  40. e=b                 ∨elim 23 39
                  41. ¬[d=e]              restate 25
                  42. ¬[d=b]              para 41 40
                  43. d=a                 ∨elim 22 42
                  44. ¬[c=d]              restate 07
                  45. ¬[c=a]              para 44 43
                  46. c=b                 ∨elim 21 45
                  47. e=c                 para 40 46
                  48. ⊥                   47 19
               49. ¬¬[e=c]              ¬intro 19 48
               50. e=c                  ¬¬elim 49
               51. Rdc                  MP 18 50
            52. Rdc                   ∃ 12 13-51
         53. ¬[c=d]→[Rdc]           →intro 07 52
            54. c=d                   assumption
            55. Rcd                   restate 06
            56. Rcc                   para 55 54
            57. Rdc                   para 56 54
         58. [c=d]→[Rdc]            →intro 54 57
         59. [c=d]∨¬[c=d]           LEM
         60. Rdc                    ∨elim 58 53 59
      61. [Rcd]→[Rdc]             →intro 06 60
      62. ∀y[[Rcy]→[Ryc]]         ∀intro 61
      63. ∀x∀y[[Rxy]→[Ryx]]       ∀intro 62
   64. ∀x∀y[[Rxy]→[Ryx]]        ∃elim 04 05-63
65. ∀x∀y[[Rxy]→[Ryx]]         ∃elim 03 04-64
66. ∀y[[Ray]→[Rya]]           ∀elim 65
67. [Rab]→[Rba]               ∀elim 66
68. ∀y[[Rby]→[Ryb]]           ∀elim 65
69. [Rba]→[Rab]               ∀elim 68
70. [Rab]↔[Rba]               ↔intro 67 69
71. ∀y[[Ray]↔[Rya]]           ∀intro 70
72. ∀x∀y[[Rxy]↔[Ryx]]         ∀intro 71
```

Synopsis of proof:

We let $Rcd$. Then, using the premise $\forall x \exists y [Rxy \land \neg x = y]$, we conclude $Rde$. Then, we argue that $e$ must be equal to $c$, using $\forall z[z = a \lor z = b]$. Then, we conclude that $Rcd \implies Rdc$. Using symmetry, we conclude that $Rdc \implies Rcd$, hence $Rcd \iff Rdc$. Then, we generalize to $\forall x \forall y[Rxy \iff Ryx]$.

Comment: Isn't this a Fitch style proof instead of a Gentzen style proof?

Comment: @DanielMak I have no energy to convert a 72-line Fitch-style into Gentzen-style...